# VBscript to read excel - 1. How to get the row count of specific column ,2 - to get the column count of specific row

Tags: excel, vbscript

VBscript to read excel:

```
Path="C:\temp\sample.xlsx"

Set objexl  = Createobject("Excel.application")

objexl.visible = False

set objwkb = objexl.workbooks.open(path)

set objsht = objwkb.sheets(1)

msgbox objsht.usedrange.rows.count  

msgbox objsht.usedrange.columns.count
```

In the above code I'm using `usedrange.rows.count` (which will display the last used row in the whole sheet) and `usedrange.columns.count` (which will display the last used column in the whole sheet).

But need the code to find

1. The row count of specific column.
2. The column count of specific row.

Before answering please consider:

1. I don't need the code to get the count by connecting to excel by DB.
2. I don't need the code to get the count by using loops.
3. I'm using external vbscript so no need of `sheets(1).cells(row,col).end(xlup).row`

Please let me know if there is any other way to find this.

Comment: It seems that you have eliminated every possibility to get the counts :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
Const xltoleft = -4159  
Const xlup = -4162 
Lst_row = Sheets(1).cells(row, col).End(xlup).row
Lst_col = Sheets(1).Cells(row, col).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

If you are using external vbscript this const values for `xltoleft`, `xlup` need to be declared.

Const values can be found out in the excel vba window by simply `Msgbox xlup` or `Msgbox xltoleft`.

Comment: Don't forget to define `row` and `col`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a late revert for this query, I found this answer might be useful.

```
Path="C:\temp\sample.xlsx"
Set objexl  = Createobject("Excel.application")
objexl.visible = False
set objwkb = objexl.workbooks.open(path)
set objsht = objwkb.sheets(1)

lngNoOfCols = objsht.Range("XFD4").End(-4159).column
lngNoOfRows = objsht.Range("A65536").End(-4162).Row
```

No. Of columns(lngNoOfCols)-XFD4(Here 4 is the number of row in which you maximum data)

Answer (score 0):

As I have some issues with the first proposal I put the code I used.
Quite similar but using down and right instead of up and left.

```
row = 1
col = 1
Const xlDown = -4121
Const xlToRight = -4161
Lst_row = Sheets(1).cells(row, col).End(xlDown).row
Lst_col = Sheets(1).Cells(row, col).End(xlToRight).Column
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30682549)